# Ubuntu won't show up no matter what in boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, software-installation

I have Windows 10 home 20H2 installed in my HP Envy, I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10 by dual booting.

I tried to install Ubuntu manually creating swap root home, everything went well, it asked to restart, after restart windows 10 loaded normally, I checked boot menu, only windows 10 was there, NO Ubuntu :(

I again tried by installing Ubuntu by using "install Ubuntu alongside windows boot manager", Everything went well but windows was only there after everything.

There is no sign that the UBUNTU is installed.

Secure boot was on and I decrypted the disk during second try.

Comment: What model HP? Many with HP have said UEFI update resolves some issues. And HP does not seem to recognize efibootmgr's change of boot order. You have to change from within UEFI. HP change boot order in UEFI boot
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2441981&p=13952881#post13952881 &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: HP- Envy 17m-ce1xxx.
I'll check about that UEFI update, I presume its a firmware update right?
I didn't find the ubuntu in boot order at all.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair HP Envy 17 - 18.04.1 works See post #3
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392797

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you!!
seems like there is so much to configure so I'll use VMware workstation instead of dual booting.
I hope HP changes this behavior at least in the future, or I'll buy some other OEM in future.
Thanks!